# Store image in cache Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, lazy-loading

In UITableviewcell I have many Image view which will load the image from url

I want to store the image in cache so that when I scroll again it should not load from url

My Code is

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
                [indicator startAnimating];
                [indicator setCenter:cell.image_VW.center];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:indicator];
NSString *url_STR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@news/%@",IMAGE_URL,[tmp_NEWS valueForKey:@"image"]];              
NSString *url_STR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@news/%@",IMAGE_URL,[tmp_NEWS valueForKey:@"image"]];                  
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   //retrive image on global queue
   UIImage * img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_STR]]];
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     [indicator removeFromSuperview];
   NEWS_BIG_CELL * cell = (NEWS_BIG_CELL *)[self.tbl_CONTENTS cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   //assign cell image on main thread
   //cell.image_VW.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            cell.image_VW.image = img;
   });
});
```

Comment: use SDwebimageview,

Answer (score 0):

you should use NSCache, where you can save you images by keys and get them if they are exist in cache (by key), please see this swift example :

http://www.splinter.com.au/2015/09/24/swift-image-cache/

or use:

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

For Simple solution is `SDWebImage` for caching image [gitHub](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) link

in your UITableviewcell `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    [cell.image_VW sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if the data is not nil from **dataWithContentsOfURL**, then if the check is true:

you can save the image as NSData in **NSUserdefaults** with its URL as the key (**setObject:(NSData) forKey:(URL as NSString)**) of that preference, so that next time, you can check in the cache if any data exists for the URL to display it immediately without getting it again from the internet (**objectForKey:(URL as NSString)**).

Comment: Means if I have n number of image also will NSUserdefaults store that many data  ... ?